# hsqldb messing up with my server´s logs

Tags: java, logging, hsqldb

I have a server I made in Java that needs to use a database, I chose HSQLDB.

So I have a lot of entries in my server like:

```
Logger.getLogger(getClass().getName()).  severe or info  ("Some important information");
```

When I run my server it goes to `System.out` which I think its the default configuration of `java.util.logging?`, so far its ok for me, and later I will make it go to a file ...

But, the problem is, when I start hsqldb it messes up with the default configuration and I can´t read my log entries on `System.out` anymore..

I already tried to change `hsqldb.log_data=false`, but it still messes up the default configuration.

Can someone help me??
I dont want to log hsqldb events, just my server ones.

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This issue was reported and fixed in the latest version 2.2.0 released today.

Basically, you set a system property `hsqldb.reconfig_logging` to the
string value `false`.

A system property is normally set with the -D option in the Java startup command for your application:

java -Dhsqldb.reconfig_logging=false ....

See below for details of the change:

http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?func=detail&aid=3195462&group_id=23316&atid=378131

In addition, when you use a fremework logger for your application, you should configure it directly to choose which levels of log to accept and which ones to ignore.

The `hsqldb.applog` setting does not affect framework logging and only controls the file log.

The `hsqldb.log_data=false` is for turning off internal data change logging and should not be used for normal databases. Its usage for bulk imports is explained in the Guide.

Comment: im using hsqldb 2.2.0, and tryed to start it using: hsqldb.reconfig_logging=false or hsqldb.reconfig_logging='false', but it didnt work.....its is just making severe level logs to system.out, but not info level

Comment: I said `you set a system property`. I'll add a paragraph to explain.

Comment: oh thank you, it really worked, sorry I didnt see the 'System.property' part, it worked using: System.setProperty("hsqldb.reconfig_logging", "false");

Comment: Why is it necessary to specify a system property telling hsqldb not to mess up your logging? Why not make the default behavior leave everything alone?

Answer (score 1):

Try setting `hsqldb.applog` to `0`, that shuts off application logging to the `*.app.log` file.

Answer (score 0):

Start your server with a property pointing to the location of a dedicated properties file:

-Djava.util.logging.config.file=/location/of/your/hsqldblog.properties"

Which contains the following line to change Java logging for Hsqldb.

```
# Change hsqldb logging level 
org.hsqldb.persist = WARNING
```

Side note, you can choose from the following levels:

SEVERE WARNING INFO CONFIG FINE FINER FINEST